# I can't get to the success block of my jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a little stuck on my jquery function below.

Here is the situation:

1) My php returns valid `JSON` - I can test this when I change the `$_POST` into `$_GET` and manually pass through data with the url.

2) The function below works correctly right up to the `$.ajax` part.

3) The function always returns `ready state 0`

Let me know if you need anymore data. Days of going over Stack Overflow and other forums has helped with insight, but I can not seem to fix in my instance.

```
//HTML
<form class="login-form"  method="POST">
    <input type="text"      id="name"   name="name"     value="" placeholder="Username" required="yes">
    <input type="password"  id="pwd"    name="pwd"      value="" placeholder="Password" required="yes">
    <input type="submit"    id="login"  name="login"    value="Login" class="loginbutton" >
</form>

//JavaScript
$('#login').click(function(event) 
{
    //event.preventDefault();

    var u = $('#name').val();
    var p = $('#pwd').val();

    console.log(u, p);
    console.log("I am seeing this function?");

    $.ajax({

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/login.php",
        data: {name:u, pwd:p},
        datatype: "json",
        error: function(msg)
        {
            console.log("RS - "+msg.readyState);    
            console.log(msg);
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {   
            console.log("RS - "+msg.readyState);
            console.log(msg);

            $.each( msg, function( i, val ) {
                console.log(val[0].session); //session is a variable in the json string
            });

            console.log("Success block");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Is anything written in console or in network tab?

Comment: Add two more arguments to the error callback. What are they?

Comment: Yes - that is all fine, otherwise I couldn't tell you that the ready state is returning - and the function worked correctly up to a certain point.

Comment: your `contentType` doesn't match your `data`, fyi.

Comment: Try to remove `contentType`

Comment: typo: `datatype` -> `dataType`

Comment: The contentType removed does not change the result sorry - still ending up in the error block

Comment: have you added the two additional arguments to the error block yet?

Comment: Yes - I did, they return the correct values.

Comment: Are you sure that error function is fired? Because I do not see any `return false` or `preventDefault` at the end, so your formular can be sent. (i want to be sure). Stupid question- do you return any json in `login.php`?

Comment: That is it - I had a prevent default in there, but had it at the start. It stuffed up something else so I removed it for the question. Now it is at the end and the function works as expected :-)

Comment: @JozefDúc Want to create an answer for the comment I upvoted? Maybe explain what it is that the preventDefault does? :-) Score a few extra points

Comment: @JeffKranenburg I can, but first I must see original code without changes.

Comment: can you provide your html too with form and button declaration, please?

Comment: not hard to look up what `event.preventDefault()` does yourself. Use browser dev tools to inspect the actual request itself to see that what is being returned is what you expect

Comment: Was more after the completeness of the question and for reference to other SO users.

Comment: So people should go and copy paste what is already well documented for the sake of "completeness"? Sounds more like laziness to me

Comment: So I was lazy for asking the question? It seems it is not as easy to find as you make it out to be. Sure it will be documented, but does this place not provide a safe place for people to learn??

Answer (score 0):

datatype -> dataType problem, and if it does not help try out the 'text' type.
Maybe the php server send out other lines that messes up things.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` or `return false` is missing at the end of your event handler for the click. Citation from `w3schools`

> The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.

so in our case it prevents form from sending.

These two technics prevent an event from bubbling upper. Without them, the form is sent to itself (address of your script) which results into page refresh and stop executing the script.

You can see the result (`readyState`) from `$.ajax()` function because it is faster than page reload.